# How to hide VBO multipage selector in a view

Tags: views

I want to hide / disable the VBO multipage selector above the table in my view but I don't find where to do it.

Anyone has an idea?

[image: VBO]

---

---

**EDIT:**
I am using the "VBO Export" module and my view is related to a media.
Here is a screenshot of the field : "Global: Views bulk operations"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

on your views, it should be a field "Content: Node operations bulk form"

[image]

if you want totaly remove VBO, hide or remove the field, but if you want to hide specified action use " Only selected actions"

[image]

Comment: I don't see this parameter. Maybe because my view is related to a media? I am also using the VBO Export module so my field is a "Global: Views bulk operations" not a "Content: Node operations bulk form".

Comment: I added some screenshot in question description :)